# Does map of stacks require n square space?

Tags: data-structures, tree, stl, binary-tree, space-complexity

I was working on this [geeksforgeeks question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/check-mirror-in-n-ary-tree1528/1#):

> ### Check Mirror in N-ary tree
>
> Given two **n**-ary trees. Check if they are mirror images of each other or not. You are also given **e** denoting the number of edges in both trees, and two arrays, **A[]** and **B[]**. Each array has 2*e space separated values u,v denoting an edge from u to v for the both trees.

So the given parameters are two arrays representing edges between the nodes of two trees (`arr1[0]` has an edge with `arr1[1]` and `arr1[2]` has and edge with `arr1[3]` and so on).

I did it using two 2-D vectors by just pushing the edges for both trees on their nodes and then reversing all edges of one tree and finally checking if now all edges of both trees are same .

It was a correct answer, but the optimal solution required should be using O(n) space, which I clearly violated using a 2-D array. (n=number of nodes)

Their solution uses a map defined as `map<int,stack<int>> m` and then similar kind of approach what I used.

My question is, is it really a O(n) space solution? Doesn't a map of stacks require n<sup>2</sup> space as every index will be using a stack of O(n) size?

Also, any hints regarding any other optimal solution (with respect to space, timely optimal solutions I wish to find on my own) will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is some ambiguity in the definition of
: there is mention of -ary trees and of  nodes. Let's speak of -ary trees instead, to avoid confusion. But honestly, I think the original question (on GfG) should not have spoken of "-ary trees" (which tells something about the branching factor, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree)), but of "trees with  nodes".

> Does map of stacks do not require n squared space as every index will be using a stack of O(n) size ?

No, even though one stack *could* have O() size, one such large stack restricts the sizes of the other stacks. A tree has O() edges -- actually, exactly −1 edges -- so the *sum* of the sizes of the stacks is still O(), and so the total memory usage is O() for the key/reference pairs in the map, and O() for the stacks, which amounts to O().

Comment: It was helpful and educative ,, thank you sir trincot !!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right. The `map<int,stack<int>> m` based solution can amount to O(n<sup>2</sup>) space. And I think it is not possible to do it in less than that amount of space because let's say to compare level `k`, you would need to store all the nodes of that to check if they are in reverse order or not. And any level `k > =2`, considering `root = level 1` will have more than `n` nodes.
In terms of time complexity, I think I have a better solution which does not use any map because maps take O(logn) time for insertion or searching.

```
using pii = pair<int, int>;
int checkMirrorTree(int n, int e, vi A, vi B) {
    if(e==0)return true;
    if(A[0]!=B[0])return false;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(A[0]);
    int i = 0;
    while(i<(2*e) && !q.empty()){
        int c = q.size();
        vector<pii> arr, arr1;
        w(i, c);ce
        while(c--){
            int root = q.front();
            q.pop();
            while(i<(2*e) && A[i]==root){
                q.push(A[i+1]);
                arr.push_back({A[i], A[i+1]});
                arr1.push_back({B[i], B[i+1]});
                i+=2;
            }   
        }
        w(i, c);ce
        int j=0;int k = arr.size()-1;
        w(k, j);ce
        w(arr, arr1);ce
        while(j<=k){
            if(arr[j]!=arr1[k])return false;
            j++;
            k--;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```